# The bean 'dataSource', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$H

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using `Spring Boot Security OAuth2` example by taking reference from https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-oauth2-example. In this example, I'm suing `Spring Boot Parent` version `2.1.1.RELEASE` and `spring-cloud-dependencies` is `Finchley.SR2`.

Error:

```
2019-01-01 20:34:07.065  INFO 15028 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79e639d7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

2019-01-01 20:34:08.724  INFO 15028 --- [           main] c.d.SpringBootSecurityOauth2Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-01 20:34:09.360  INFO 15028 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-01-01 20:34:09.411  INFO 15028 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 43ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-01-01 20:34:09.815  WARN 15028 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] for bean 'dataSource': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=refresh; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] bound.
2019-01-01 20:34:09.835  INFO 15028 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-01 20:34:09.837 ERROR 15028 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'dataSource', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
#    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: root
    password: root

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
```

User.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column(length = 60)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @Column
    private long salary;

    @Column
    private int age;
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "devglan-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "devglan-secret";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1 * 60 * 60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6 * 60 * 60;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer.inMemory().withClient(CLIEN_ID).secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Spring Cloud Finchley release train is not compatible to Spring Boot 2.1.x out of the box. You need to upgrade from `Finchley.SR2` to `Greenwich.RELEASE`.

See the [section “Release Trains” on the Spring Cloud homepage](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#release-trains):

[image: Spring Cloud compatibility matrix]

Comment: For spring-boot-starter-parent  2.2.4.RELEASE, changing spring-cloud version from Finchley to Hoxton.RELEASE solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In application.properties

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Please see and add the last 2 lines inside your application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
#    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: root
    password: root

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Comment: Try changing your spring cloud dependency to Greenwich.M3

Answer (score 1):

Adding this annotation in the application file above the class declaration worked for me:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the pvorb answer. That also helped me after searching for hours what was wrong with the code.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        **<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>**
    </properties>
```